# Same height for matrices regardless of fractions inside

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, fractions, wiki

How can I force matrices (`bmatrix`) with the same number of rows to be the same height when only some entries include fractions (`\frac`)?

I would prefer to increase the size of matrices displayed smaller, rather than decreasing the size of matrices that contain fractions.

```
R(\theta) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -\tan\frac\theta2 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} % this matrix is displayed smaller than the others
   1 & 0 \\ \sin\theta & 1    % <- no fraction here
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -\tan\frac\theta2 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
```

Here's how this equation is diplayed on Wikipedia:

[image]

I cannot use arbitrary packages nor can I redefine anything, because I encountered this inside `<math>` on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Decomposition_into_shears).

Comment: You have only provided a code snippet, not an MWE.  When I insert the snippet into the simplest possible code, the matrix heights **are** all the same.  Thus, you have not provided enough information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: You could put a `\vphantom{\frac\theta2}` in the cells not containing a fraction.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz this is about maths on wikipedia. `\vphantom` doesn't work there. However, this question is arguably off-topic as it is not about LaTeX, but about things that use similar syntax to LaTeX.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue you claim to have encountered when I compile the samle document. In particular, all three `bmatrix` environments would appear to be equally tall.

Comment: @Mico this is about `<math>` on Wikipedia, not LaTeX (off topic?).

Comment: @rbrignall -- Aah, I had completely missed that the question was specific to the Wikipedia site.

Comment: @mico Why did you remove [tag:wiki] and add [tag:amsmath]? Any answer to this question should consider the constraints imposed by the capabilities of Tex supported by Mediawiki and its configuration as used by Wikimedia for Wikipedia.

Comment: Ok, maybe Wikipedia doesn't use MathML, but it uses something weird, imho, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula

Comment: How is this question off-topic, if there is even a dedicated tag (i.e. `wiki`) for it? I will raise that issue on meta.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to recreate the issue you've experienced on the Wikipedia site by using `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`.

I can think of three possible work-arounds.

- The first solution relies on inserting a typographic strut. This method is feasible only if the `\vphantom` directive is available.
- The second method employs `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` (or `\dfrac`). Given that wikipedia's math software "understands" other macros provided by the `amsmath` package, it may also understand `\tfrac`.
- The third employs inline-fraction notation instead of `\frac`. It should be feasible everywhere, including on Wikipedia sites.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'bmatrix' environments
% create a typographic strut:
\newcommand\mystrut{\ensuremath{\vphantom{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
R(\theta) 
&= \begin{bmatrix} % original form
   1 & -\tan\dfrac\theta2 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\ \sin\theta & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -\tan\dfrac\theta2 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix} &&\text{Problem recreated with \texttt{\string\dfrac}}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} % first solution
   1 & -\tan\dfrac\theta2 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0\mystrut \\ \sin\theta & 1 % <-- note "\mystrut"
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -\tan\dfrac\theta2 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix} &&\text{Solution 1: Insert a typographic strut} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} % second solution
   1 & -\tan\tfrac\theta2 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\ \sin\theta & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -\tan\tfrac\theta2 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix} &&\text{Solution 2: Use \texttt{\string\tfrac}}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} % third solution
   1 & -\tan(\theta/2) \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\ \sin\theta & 1 
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -\tan(\theta/2) \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix} &&\text{Solution 3: Use inline-fraction notation}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```